# How to reassign a time_point from clock::now()?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

Given a `std::chrono::sys_seconds time`, one might expect to reassign `time` from its clock with something like:

```cpp
time = decltype(time)::clock::now();
```

However, this would likely fail, because `decltype(time)::clock::duration` has nothing to do with `decltype(time)`. Instead it is a predefined unit(likely finer than `seconds`), so you would have to manually cast it to a coarser unit.

Which means you would need to write something like:

```cpp
time = std::chrono::time_point_cast<decltype(time)::duration>(decltype(time)::clock::now());
```

---

So my question is if there is a shorter syntax to do this?

Comment: Once you have a `duration`, you can just divide it by `1s` to get its value in seconds. But I'm not sure what the types you have 'declared' in your post actually are.

Comment: ... something like `auto secs = (std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point{}) / 1s;`.

Comment: @AdrianMole `time` is a `time_point<system_clock, seconds>`. But the point of my questions is to get a new `now` based on the same clock and same duration of `time`. So your suggested code need to be written like `new_time = (decltype(time)::clock::now() - decltype(time)::clock::time_point{}) / decltype(time)::duration{1} + decltype(time){}`

Comment: I would use `time = floor<seconds>(system_clock::now());`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant But that would only work if I knew `time` is `time_point<system_clock, seconds>`. If I don't, I would need to get the duration type and clock type from `time`'s type.

Comment: I don't think a get and a cast is any long. you may write a function to do it anyway.

Comment: @appleapple I agree. It's mostly about *if* there is a shorter syntax for it(feels like a pretty common way people would want to use it).

Comment: @Ranoiaetep well I think it's not that common someone don't know the `clock` and `duration` type and then need to retrieve the time and assign to same duration. (for example  `auto t = clock::now(); t = clock::now();` just works)

Comment: @appleapple I agree not knowing `clock` is less common. But I won't be surprised if someone stored `t` with `seconds` precision, and then they can't use `now()` directly without manually casting the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an obvious solution is just write your own function

```cpp
template<typename Clock, typename Duration>
void SetNow(std::chrono::time_point<Clock,Duration>& time){
    time = std::chrono::time_point_cast<Duration>(Clock::now());
}

// use
void foo(){
    auto time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    SetNow(time);
}
```

---

you can also do some fancy overload

```cpp
struct Now_t{
    template<typename Clock,typename Duration>
    operator std::chrono::time_point<Clock,Duration>()const{
        return std::chrono::time_point_cast<Duration>(Clock::now());
    }
    consteval Now_t operator()()const{return {};} // enable time = Now();
} Now;

// use
void foo() {
    auto time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    time = Now;
    time = Now();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a generic context where you don't know the precise type of `time`, then I find it convenient to set up using declarations for `clock` and `duration`:

```
template <class TimePoint>
void
assign(TimePoint& time)
{
    using clock = typename TimePoint::clock;
    using duration = typename TimePoint::duration;
    time = std::chrono::floor<duration>(clock::now());
}
```

I chose `floor` as the rounding mode (always down) so that this will have the same behavior prior to the epoch as after.  Some clock's current time can be prior to the epoch, such as `file_clock` on gcc.  But if you prefer truncation towards zero, `time_point_cast` will work as well.